# Failed to maintain projects LRU cache for dir

Tags: android-studio, installation

Just reinstalled my Android Studio, after launching I get this error:

Failed to maintain projects LRU cache for dir C:\Users\Username\.AndroidStudio2.2\system\resource_folder_cache: invalid stream header: 00000000

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Select "File"->"Invalidate Caches/Restart...". I think it will help.